# Ubuntu 20.04 Dual Boot Overheating in Dell Inspiron 5402

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, 20.04, dell, overheating

I own a brand new Dell Inspiron 5402. According to Dell, it should support Ubuntu 20.04 (https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-ph/drivers/supportedos/inspiron-14-5402-laptop?ref=oscompatibility). According to Canonical, the laptop should support it as well (https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/202007-28054).

I don't know why it keeps overheating when the laptop is just on. No applications are running but it is hot to the touch.

Comment: I know you say no apps are running but what is the cpu load when it gets hot? Does the same thing happen on Windows? Could be faulty hardware.

Comment: How do you know its overheating?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! It's overheating because I checked with the sensors console app. It said 90°C (critical is 100°C). I checked the CPU usage as well. I have 4 CPUs. None of which go above 10%. As for Windows, I haven't checked the temperature directly but it's cold to the touch. Ubuntu is significantly hotter.

Comment: UPDATE: I disabled NVIDIA via the NVIDIA X Server Settings app. It seems to have worked a bit. It's cooler now. Readings are 60°C but still warm to the touch (though colder than previously). It's still weird that it feels warm though since I'm just letting the computer stay on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using an NVIDIA MX330 graphics card. I think that's the root of the problem.

The first time my computer turned on, I immediately went to NVIDIA X Server Settings (pre installed upon initial boot) in my apps and changed the PRIME Profiles to Intel (Power Saving Mode). Note that I did not attempt any updates or anything at this point. I only turned on Power Saving Mode.

After that, I restarted the computer and did an update then upgrade command:

`sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade`

It had a temperature of 60°C. I restarted the computer again and it would usually be at around 40°C when idle. 60°C when I'm doing something intensive like watching YouTube videos while I code.

I'm too afraid to use the NVIDIA GPU for now. I will probably wait for someone to confirm that Ubuntu 20.04 works well with this laptop or GPU before I try using it again.